# I want to know the meaning of "a sentence with present participle"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference, present-participles

There are many people wishing to visit the temple.
If I rephrase this sentence like :—

- There are many people who wish to visit the temple.
  Or,
- There are many people who are wishing to visit the temple.

Which one is correct and why?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Someone said me 1st one is correct.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is it allowed by English to use one sentence to express different meaning???

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I expressed the sentence in two different ways, is it possible in English, Using one sentence to mean different. (Ex:-....People wishing....=1)....people who are wishing....Or 2)...People who wish...)

Comment: Yes it is possible to have one sentence with two different meanings, this is called ambiguity.  It is even more likely to have one sentence with two different translations. This is because languages don't have one-to-one correspondence, and you may well confuse "the meaning" with "the translation".

Comment: @JamesK yes, plz clarify.. And give full answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,  it can be hard to distinguish "meaning" from "translation".  When we want to know the meaning of something in English, we often use translation to a native language.  This can cause some confusion, as English sententence don't always map one-to-one to native language sentences.

Now English has two (main) aspects for the present tense: simple present and present continuous. These have similar meanings. In some languages there may not be separate aspects, or there may be more aspects of the present tense that don't exist in English.

Now it is also possible to "rephrase" an English sentence in English.  This is rather like doing a translation.  The rephrasing may capture much of the original meaning.

So with the phrase "people wishing to visit the temple".  We have a noun "people" modified by a participle clause.  This could be rephrased using a relative clause: "people who ...." but the relative clause has a finite verb in it.  So we need to choose tense and aspect for this verb.

Right, so consider "There are people eating chips outside".  The aspect is clearly right now, so if I rephrase with a relative clause I'd choose "There are people who are eating chips".

What about "wish", well this is more stative, so tends to be used in the simple present rather than continuous.  "There are people wishing to enter the temple" could be rephrased as "There are people who wish to enter the temple".

So does this mean that "people wishing" should always be rephrased as "people who wish".  Not so. Consider "Last year, many people wishing to enter the temple came to India".  If we want to rephrase this we notice that the tense we notice that the relative clause probably should be in the past tense "Last year, many people who wished to enter the temple...".

Can a single phrase have different rephrasings according to context? Yes it can. This is called ambiguity. A sentence, much less a phrase, does not have a single "meaning" and certainly not a single "translation" or "rephrasing. It may have many.

However for your specific case, and taking into account the context of what "wishing to enter the temple"  means, the simple present is best.  "People who wish to enter the temple."